# How to execute mail in background codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, background-process

Hi am developing one CI application. That application contains user registration, After user registration. I want send 8 emails so it will take more time to execute. how to avoid this and run emails in background?

Comment: Sending only eight email will not take more time to execute. If you need background process use cron job.

Comment: or use `ajax`, after you get to page, lets say `thank you for contact us` send ajax request to a specified action to produce the email method. Also consider this: https://github.com/izn/codeigniter-mailqueue

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco but it will wait. that means processing..... after sent all mail then only do next task right?

Comment: If you will use ajax, it will run this process in background, as far as you not waiting any response. Doing this with Queue, it will be stored in DB and run as small as every minute.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco you mean cron tab? is there any other way instead of cron job?

Comment: What concerns do you have on proposed variants?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco why we unwanted run cron every minutes?

Comment: Cron will check every minute for unfinished tasks in specified DB. But if you do not have a lot of visitors right now you can chose an ajax method.